# Green's function for fractional operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fractional-calculus

I am studying some papers about the fractional laplacian, and I am stuck on a formula that I do not understand. I would like to ask if anybody can give me some help.
In [this paper](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/697638/arXiv%202010%20Kenig.pdf), on page 12, there is a formula for the Green function $G_\alpha$ of a problem in $1+1$ dimensions. However, in [this paper by Xavier Cabré](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.0867.pdf), it seems to me that the Green function should have a completely different form, as noticed in Remarks 3.8 and 3.10. In particular, I do not understand the presence of an exponential term in the paper by Kenig. 
So my question is: what is the relationship between the function $G_\alpha$ of the first paper and the functions appearing in Remarks 3.8 and 3.10 of the second paper?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Kenig-Martel-Robbiano study a parabolic problem while Cabré-Sire study an elliptic problem. For ordinary Laplacian, the heat kernel $t^{-n/2}e^{-|x|^2/(4t)}$ does not look very much like the fundamental solution $|x|^{2-n}$ either.

Comment: After some more thoughts, I think they solve different problems. While Cabré solves $(-\Delta)^su=h$, Kenig *et al.* solve $(-\Delta)^s u+u=h$. It is not trivial to move from one equation to the other. Even for the ordinary laplacian, the Green function for $-\Delta+I$ decays exponentially fast at infinity, while the Green function for $-\Delta$ decays like a negative power. But there is still something I do not understand completely.

Comment: I know this question is 3 years old, but I think I need the paper dealing with $-\Delta^s u + u$ by Kenig et al. However, your links are dead. Do you happen do know the sources? That would be great!